# Блокировка пользователя телеграмм с помощью telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, telethon

Пытался найти метод для блокировки пользователя (собеседника в чате) функцию, но поисковик ничего не выдаёт, в документации не нашел. Знаете кто нибудь как с помощью telethon  заблокировать чат?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70815872/12785139

Answer (score 0):

```
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import BlockRequest

def block_user_by_username(username):

    try:
        target_user = client.get_entity(username)
        client(BlockRequest(target_user.id))
        print(f"Пользователь с username {username} был успешно заблокирован.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Произошла ошибка при блокировке пользователя: {e}")
```

Заблокирует человека в личке, как минимум.